How to apply FDR correction, and which method is most appropriate?
So I am a little confused with the application of q-values or more broadly, FDR correction (BH or BKY).
I have run multiple linear mixed effect models to assess the impact of medication on several brain regions and have a total of 245 p-values in a matrix.
Do I apply the q-value method to the entire matrix of q-values? or should I apply it by region? (lets say there are appox 30 p-values for each region)
Likewise, If i was to use the BH or BKY FDR correction method, would I apply this to the entire matrix or by region?
If i do decide to go with the q-value approach, do I have enough p-values to produce robust q-values?
Finally, which method is more robust overall? I dont want to be overly conservative but I also want to adequately control for type-1 errors.
Note, there is no problem with my r code, I understand how to apply each FDR procedure, I'm just finding it difficult to find oncrete infromation on whether to apply to the entire model (which I would likely do with the q-value approach considering it will likely underperform with such low amounts of p-values by region) or by region?
Any advice would be greatly appeciated

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My only answer for all your questions is: It depends.
But I will provide general information about multiple testing and related corrections.
Briefly you have two possibilities, controlling the Family-Wise Error Rate (FWER) or controlling the False Discovery Rate (FDR).
It is commonly accepted that controlling the FWER will lead to more conservative results resulting in weakest powers, while controlling the FDR is less stringent, therefore more powerful.
That's being said the q-value can be seen as controlling the FDR but has some bayesian properties.
Ultimately, we do not talk about robustness but choosing the right procedure depending on your goals. Here, I would suggest going with controlling the FDR using Benjamini and Hochberg or the q-value.
Finally, if you run a model by region, you have to correct for the multiplicity between models not within models.
To conclude, before going any further, a good starting point is to plot some histograms or qq-plots of your unadjusted p-values.
